# Can wifi speed on a laptop be limited by i7 core processor?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, internet-speed

Can someone dumb this down for me or help with a solution? I have an i7 Core Processor in my Inspiron HP laptop and am not getting full wifi speeds from our Comcast/Xfinity X6 modem/router. Sitting at my desk, my laptop only gets around 100MBPS. But sitting at my desk next to my laptop, I get over 400MBPS download speed on my iPhone from that same router/modem. Also get the same higher speed from an iPad. Could it be that my laptop processor won't handle that speed? Thx for any help on this.

Comment: Its something else restricting bandwidth.

Comment: It's probably not your laptop - but there's a lot of missing information. Critically - at these ranges, what is your wireless nic? A lot of laptops cheap out and use single band cards with fewer streams

Answer (score 0):

Other wireless devices can create communications complications when placed in close proximity to each other. Routers using 2.4 GHz bands are using the same electromagnetic spectrum as many house wireless telephone systems. If there is a telephone base station near your router or near your receiving device, you may experience the problem you describe.

With the expanding variety of wireless devices in today's household, it's not limited to only household telephone handsets. If you have other devices using the same bandwidth, you'd want to move them out of the area as much as practical. The more powerful devices can require more spacing than lower powered ones.